# AngularJS complains that initialization not defined for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I am getting the below error when loading my page.

> Error: initialize is not defined
>   @http://localhost:8082/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.js line 339 > eval:4:3

I want to replace the jqLite with the full version of jquery.  I have read several stackoverflow questions on this subject and they imply that all that is required is to load jquery before angularjs.  I have done this by simply moving the  declaration for jquery above the angular.js.  When I do this that is when the above error occurs.  It does not give the error when I move the jquery below angularjs but then I cannot use such things as angular.element.

What am I doing wrong?

As far as loading the javascript for each library all I am doing is.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/vendor/angular.js"></script>
```

as far as using jquery instead of lqlite, I am simply trying to use  angular.element

```
var someElement = angular.element('#someelement');
```

I read a blurb to load jquery before DOMContentLoaded.  I am not sure how to do this.  I know how to write an event handler for DOMContentLoaded, but what do I do then.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to load and initialize these scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited answer:** I usually inject my JS script code in the header all inside of an IFFE. You'd also have to make sure you have the ng-app in there to specify the module. Finally I've made sure I actually include the dependent code in the **header** before my code. 
See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gkohen/d3jwbmd4/27/)

```
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script> 
<script>
    (function() {
      var testApp = angular.module("testApp", []);
      function SomeController($scope) {
        console.log('Started controller');  
        $scope.dirPanelElement = angular.element('#some-panel');
        $scope.dirPanelElement.text('set test');
        $scope.dirPanelElementText='got "'+$scope.dirPanelElement.text()+'" from panel'         
      }
    testApp.controller("SomeController", SomeController);
   })(); // IFFE
</script>
</head>
 <body ng-app='testApp'>
  <div id="content">
   <div style="padding:50px">
    <div data-ng-controller="SomeController">
       <p align="center">Something</p>
       <div id="some-panel"></div>
       <div id="some-canvas">{{dirPanelElementText}}</div>  
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: <body data-ng-controller="MainController">

<script type='text/javascript' src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/vendor/angular.js"></script>   same error

Comment: Please check in the network tab of the browser's dev tools your not getting a 404 response on getting the jquery file.

Comment: ]I am not getting a 404 error.  If I move the script declaration for jquery below all the angular declaration then I do not get load error but I get an error when the angular.element is called, "[jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org".  Also under Firefox's Firebug, all the scripts are loaded.  Is there a certain version of jquery that needs to be loaded for each version of anglar?  I am using AngularJS v1.2.10 and jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.2.

Comment: Is it something that you could recreate on JSFiddle or happens only locally? If you can recreate it on JSF, do you mind sending a link?

Comment: I will try this. I am using a node server as the backend.  I noticed that node logges  the GET on the angular.js before it does the jquery.  Can I assume this is the order that node is serving the files?  Also can I assume this is the order that my browser is loading them as well?

Comment: The order in which they load is async but the order the code is executed should really be in order.

Comment: I have entered a stripped down version of the code on JSFiddle.  I am new to JSFiddle.  It is not working but I think that you can at least see what I am doing.   https://jsfiddle.net/d532335/j2j05a9o/